# Can't configure Wacom tablet stylus

Tags: wacom

I'm using **Ubuntu 18.04**, installed it on a clean HDD 5 days ago.
I've just plugged in my Wacom tablet - which is **Wacom Bamboo CTL-470**, and *it worked instantly* - stylus moves the mouse around, applications can read pressure, and stylus's touching and both buttons are mapped to left, middle and right mouse button.

In system settings>Devices>Wacom Tablet, "Tablet" page works, but **"Stylus" page doesn't** - it says "No stylus found" no matter what - and yes, I did hover my stylus over the tablet - even tried holding it above the tablet while rebooting, and on bootup it still didn't find it.

I'd like to rebind one of the buttons to CTRL+Z, but with it not detecting the stylus it doesn't want to show me the settings.

Any attempts to look up this problem on the internet resulted only in me finding solutions for the problem when that tablet doesn't work completely, and for older versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: welcome to AskUbuntu! you might need to use GnomeTweaks... `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` then run `gnome-tweaks` and see if you can see your stylus there....

Comment: No, I can't. I navigated through all of the menus with the stylus, and there was nothing related to the tablet or stylus anywhere.

Comment: did you try the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/wacom-stylus.html.en

Comment: Pressing on "Wacom Tablet" just redirects to that same page in Settings, and those buttons are not available since it doesn't see the stylus.

Comment: I have similar behaviour with a Thinkpad L390 Yoga running Ubuntu 19.04. The pen works but in Settings -> Devices -> Wacom Tablet, it says "no stylus found". Running "xsetwacom --list" returns "Wacom Pen and multitouch sensor Pen stylus....".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an alternative way of configuring stylus buttons if Ubuntu settings refuse to show the settings. The way is described here, in the "Wacom tablet" section on [Ubuntu 16.04 for my digital painting workstation - David Revoy](https://www.davidrevoy.com/article316/ubuntu-16-04-for-my-digital-painting-workstation):

> In Cinnamon, the GUI for Wacom tablet offer minimal yet powerful set
>   of options: set buttons, set proportions to the screen...etc... The
>   GUI is limited because you can't assign buttons modifier like  ,
>    and  ...
>
> **Xsetwacom:**    For those who really need a way to assign this key and do more, here is the (big) workaround involving command line,
>   script and other dirty things a normal user shoudn't consider as
>   something normal to setup an hardware (graphist needs a GUI and focus
>   on making good graphism, not script/code):
>
> **1.  Get your tablet device name:**
>
> ```
> xsetwacom --list
> ```
>
> This command returns the name of my Wacom device, useful for my
>   script:
>
> ```
> Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pen stylus    id: 11 type: STYLUS
> Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pad pad       id: 12 type: PAD
> Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pen eraser    id: 15 type: ERASER
> Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pen cursor    id: 16 type: CURSOR
> ```
>
> Note for reference your tablet pad name, mine here is **Wacom Intuos3
>   9x12 Pad** pad in this example. Select the name, then press
>   ++C to copy it in your terminal.
>
> **2. Create a Xsetwacom bash script**    Open the file manager (Nemo) , and in the folder of your choice ( I use /home/deevad/Script on my
>   installation ) create a new empty file with right-click , "create a
>   new document">"Empty document". Name it tablet.sh , then open it with
>   a text-editor (Gedit). Inside it write a script like this with your
>   tablet name:
>
> ```
> #! /bin/bash
> xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pad pad" Button 1 "key Shift_L"
> xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pad pad" Button 2 "key Control_L"
> ```
>
> This example script will map  to the button 1 of your tablet
>   (resize brush in Krita) , and Control to the button 2 ( pick color on
>   Krita/Gimp/Mypaint) of the tablet. The special keys use standard
>   names, for assigning other type of key I paste here a list :
>   http://pastebin.com/aXGDkJTU
>
> If you want to assign a modifier ( eg. Ctrl ) on the stylus button,
>   it's also possible:
>
> ```
> xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos3 9x12 Pen stylus" Button 2 "key ctrl"
> ```
>
> You can test all your xsetwacom lines inside the Terminal before
>   writing them in your script. This way you'll test if you have a Button
>   5 , or Button 20... etc...     For my Intuos 3, the layout of the
>   right side is like this ( I found it with guessing and trying ):
>
> ```
> # ---------
> # |   | 1 |
> # | 3 |---|
> # |   | 2 |
> # |-------|
> # |   8   |
> # ---------
> ```
>
> When your script is finished you can save it. In the file-manager ;
>   right-click on it again > Properties > Permissions > and in front of
>   Execute check the box for 'Allow executing file as a program'.
>
> **3. Run it, create a start-up**     You can double click and run the script. Your key on tablet will be mapped. But all setup of the button
>   will not last a reboot. That's why we made a script to execute it at
>   each start-up. Go now on 'System Settings', then 'Start-up
>   application' , press the 'Add' button , give the form a name of your
>   choice, for the command pick your script via the 'Browse' button, and
>   comment what you want about it.
>
> **More informations about Xsetwacom:**    http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xsetwacom

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `xf86-input-wacom` installed, if not install it and restart Xserver or reboot.

In my case, I had the kernel driver and `libwacom` installed but not xf86-input-wacom; and, I suffered of the same symptoms, though I'm using Arch and not Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

To get the stylus to work I grabbed an up-to-date version of the `libwacom.stylus` file and replaced the old version at `/usr/share/libwacom/libwacom.stylus`

You can find the up-to-date `libwacom.stylus` files on the Github: https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/tree/master/data

Comment: @josh.chavenne In my case after doing this my ubuntu did not boot any more.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wouldn't keep your system from booting, and not sure whats up with the downvote - but good luck.

Comment: @josh.chavenne I am aware that this is not understandable. But after booting in protected mode an undoing (removing the file) the system woked fine again. After all at the moment Wacom intuos definitely does not run properly in ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @ubuntuuser did you make sure the file permission and ownership were correct?